# Laravel : Clear only all database cache or clear all cache with an exception

Tags: php, caching, laravel

**Is it possible to clear only the database cache or clear all cache with an exception in `Laravel`?** I need to cache a variable result, but it will be removed when I run `Cache::Flush()` to clear mydatabase query.

Answer (score 1):

No, not using the `artisan cache:flush` command, nor the `Cache::flush()`, they accept no params.

If you wanted to do your own specific cleanup, you would need to code that yourself.

Comment: i use query cache to many query , so difficult to give a specific id

Answer (score 0):

you should try use cache tags. It is great to clean just some part of your cache http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache#cache-tags